# Convert character to Date (Thu Jun 14 *** 2018-05-14) in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which is about World Cup matches that include date,location,match_name etc.
In this dataframe I want to convert date column as date in format "2018-05-06"

Here is my file;

```
  date          match_name          price      
1 Thu Jun 14 Russia v Saudi Arabia  €453.92  
2 Fri Jun 15 Egypt v Uruguay        €90.00   
3 Tue Jun 19 Russia v Egypt         €297.45  
4 Wed Jun 20 Uruguay v Saudi Arabia €95.00
```

and here is my expectation;

```
  date          match_name          price      
1 2018-05-14 Russia v Saudi Arabia  €453.92  
2 2018-05-15 Egypt v Uruguay        €90.00   
3 2018-05-19 Russia v Egypt         €297.45  
4 2018-05-20 Uruguay v Saudi Arabia €95.00
```

Comment: unfortunately solutions gives some error and convert NA

Comment: @Hüseyin because you have to take the `substr()` with the day-and-month, then concatenate "2018". You're supposed to make a little effort to solve the problem. SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sure is not the easiest way to do it, But I just wanted you to have a quick answer.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
Data=data.frame(date=c("Thu Jun 14","Fri Jun 15","Tue Jun 19","Wed Jun 20"),match_name=c("a","b","c","d"),price=c(1,2,3,4))
Data$date=as.character(Data$date)

regexp <- "[[:digit:]]+"
Data=mutate(Data,datenum=str_extract(Data$date, regexp))
Data=mutate(Data,monthnum=str_extract(Data$date, regexp))

Data=mutate(Data,monthname=str_extract(Data$date,"Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec"))

Data=mutate(Data,monthnum=if(Data$monthname=="Jan")
                      "01"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Feb")
         "02"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Mar")
         "03"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Apr")
         "04"
       else if(Data$monthname=="May")
         "05"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Jun")
         "06"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Jul")
         "07"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Aug")
         "08"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Sep")
         "09"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Oct")
         "10"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Nov")
         "11"
       else if(Data$monthname=="Dec")
         "12"
       )
mutate(Data,Final_Date=paste0("2018-",monthnum,"-",datenum))
```

Resulting in

```
date match_name price datenum monthnum monthname Final_Date
1 Thu Jun 14          a     1      14       06       Jun 2018-06-14
2 Fri Jun 15          b     2      15       06       Jun 2018-06-15
3 Tue Jun 19          c     3      19       06       Jun 2018-06-19
4 Wed Jun 20          d     4      20       06       Jun 2018-06-20
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.It works well.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's say you have this data.frame:

```
myDF <-as.data.frame(x=list(date=c("Thu Jun 14","Fri Jun 15","Tue Jun 19","Wed Jun 20")))
```

Which constructs the following data.frame:

```
        date
1 Thu Jun 14
2 Fri Jun 15
3 Tue Jun 19
4 Wed Jun 20
```

Assuming that each game is in 2018:

```
#for handling month abbreviations in English:
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8") 

myDF$date <- as.Date(paste0(substr(myDF$date,5,10),", 2018"),format="%b %d, %Y")
```

The resulting myDF:

```
        date
1 2018-06-14
2 2018-06-15
3 2018-06-19
4 2018-06-20
```

You can change 2018 to any year you like where necessary.

Comment: That is converting date values to NA .

Answer (score 0):

To convert a variable "date" to the format '2018-05-14', you need to perform the following function:

```
conv_date <- function(var, year){
  var <- as.Date(paste0(var, " ", year), '%a %b %d %Y')
  return(var)
}
```

where:

1. var - variable in your data table (i.e 'date')
2. year - the year you need

Example:

```
yours_df$date <- conv_date(yours_df$date, 2018)
```